# No negative value for clientY in IE11 for Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

This is a very specific issue as it only applies to IE11 under Windows 8.1. You can easily track the mouse position using following code snippet:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    console.log(e.clientY);
});
```

If you paste this in the console of any browser, you will see that it outputs a negative value whenever you move your mouse to the address bar / top of your screen.

But in IE11 under Windows 8.1 the event is never triggered when `clientY` is supposedly holding negative values.

**How can I detect a user moving out of the document when I cannot detect negative values?**

Comment: Can you provide us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Mgetz: Sure, but it is basically the code that I already provided. Move your mouse out of the "Result" box. http://jsfiddle.net/aUPjz/

Comment: This only applies for IE11 in Windows 8.1. Any other combination will most likey see negative values in the console.

Comment: Which IE11? Metro or Desktop?

Comment: May I ask - why do you need to know the position when you mouse out of the document?

Comment: Desktop. But I just realized that it works with the jsFiddle. Probably because there is still a document above it. Please copy and paste that code to your console of this page for example and try to get a negative value.

Comment: @Amberlamps You can look at the jsFiddle fully by going to http://jsfiddle.net/aUPjz/show/

Comment: @Ian: Thanks. Did not know that. If you use Ian´s link, you will see the problem.

Comment: @Amberlamps IE11 is compliant with [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseout) it only requires that it gives coordinates in the viewport of the window, if the mouse is not in the window then the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: @Mgetz: THanks, but it is working with IE11 under Windows 7 though.

Comment: @Amberlamps I would not depend on anything that's not in the standard. You can report this on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) if you think it is a bug. But don't be surprised if the IE team bounce it back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [32 bits IE Toolbar not working in Win 8.1 64 bits RTM/IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850655/32-bits-ie-toolbar-not-working-in-win-8-1-64-bits-rtm-ie11)