# Debug BHO 32 Bits in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: c++, debugging, internet-explorer-10, bho

I have a BHO **32 Bits**, up to internet explorer 9 I was able to debug it by setting in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
the TabProcGrowth to 0

Now with internet explorer 10 if I use only one process (TabProcGrowth==0) my BHO isn't loaded, since of what I understood the Manager Processes always run on 64 Bits, so with that value as zero no Content Processes running in 32 Bits would be created.

So if I need to debug my BHO I need to convert it to 64 Bits?
Or is there any other registry flag that allows the debug of 32 bits bho in Internet Explorer 10 ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [32 bits IE Toolbar not working in Win 8.1 64 bits RTM/IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850655/32-bits-ie-toolbar-not-working-in-win-8-1-64-bits-rtm-ie11)