# BHO and internet explorer 11

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, bho

I saw some code on codeproject like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797515/Writing-HTML-content-to-a-webpages-DOM-with-a-Cplu) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C). but both are not compatible with the new security policy of internet explorer add-ons, when i insert then on registry they show up on the IE add-ons list, but with the "incompatible" status. Some can show me a working example for IE11 add-on? or can show me what i need to change? (i already disabled the security mode, but even with that i couldn't make it work) there is something to do with EPM (Enhanced Protected Mode)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [32 bits IE Toolbar not working in Win 8.1 64 bits RTM/IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850655/32-bits-ie-toolbar-not-working-in-win-8-1-64-bits-rtm-ie11)

Answer (score 2):

Have you used regsvr32.exe to register your BHO? I have IE 11 and used your second link as a boilerplate project, and I have no problems getting the dll to work in IE (besides having problems with working with the IE api -  but that's not relevant).

What I did to get the BHO to work:

- Have IE 11
- Have Visual Studio 2015
- Download the project from codeproject, doubleclick the solution
- Convert it to the new format and download the dependencies (VS asked me to convert it, and I didn't have VisualC++ for Visual Studio or something)
- Build it in release (I haven't actually tried debug)
- Execute regsvr32.exe in an admin command prompt
- Start IE and enable the BHO when IE asks you to

That's basically everything I did, and I didn't get an error on the way.

EDIT: Oops, sorry for necroing this. That was not my intention.

Comment: Thanks for this post, this information is impossible to find on google!