# BHO not working if compiled and registered as 64bit

Tags: c#, com, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, bho

if used this code:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSBrowserHelperObject-59c189a2
and compiled it for 64 bit. then I installed it with 64 bit regasm ( /codebase )
it shows in IE but it doesn't work (context menu is displayed)

it works fine when compiled and regasm-ed with 32bit.

my os is windows 8, and internet explorer 11 (no enhanced protection mode)

Comment: possible duplicate of [32 bits IE Toolbar not working in Win 8.1 64 bits RTM/IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850655/32-bits-ie-toolbar-not-working-in-win-8-1-64-bits-rtm-ie11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of IE are you using, 64-bit or 32-bit?  I think there are two versions on 64-bit OSes.  I am guessing that since you have success with the 32-bit BHO, then that means you are running 32-bit IE and of course a 64-bit BHO will not work with it.

Comment: Thats it, i found out that IE always opens 32-bit tabs.

Comment: Venus, Is there any way to load BHO in IE64 bit, if you have worked ?
I've tried many solutions but still no clue.

BHO is not loading in 64bit IE if I build it with 64bit compiler with 64bit DLLs.